# Regex - Combining an 'or' with a 'look-behind'

Tags: python, html, regex, lookbehind

Sorry about the confusing title. I am trying to figure out a simple Regex problem, but cannot figure out what the solution is.

I have a HTML snippet from a larger HTML document.

- `<td class="grade">100.0</td>`
- `<td class="teacher">Mathias, Jordan</td>`

Other Regex separates the two, giving them those class-names. I use a positive `look-ahead` to check for a `.` or a `,` (period or comma), and assign them the class of grade or teacher (respectively).

---

The problem comes later, when I want to check if the code in-between these tags is blank.

- i.e. : `<td class="grade"></td>`

I would like to use a positive look-behind to check if the class is either grade or teacher `(grade|teacher)`. In addition, I would like to check that there is truly nothing in between the `><` (conjunction of the empty tags).

So-far, this is what I have: `(?<=.*(teacher|grade)*.+>?)[^.](?=</td>)`

**NOTE:** This is in Python

Comment: HTML is **not** a nail-shaped problem, put down that regex-hammer. Pick up a HTML parser instead, like BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Obligatory, HTML is better parsed with an html parser, not regex

Comment: I use Regex in conjuction with BeautifulSoup. Considering the size of the HTML and its complexity, BeautifulSoup is useless in rendering the HTML unless Regex changes the class so BeautifulSoup can parse through and find it. @MartijnPieters

Comment: `soup.find_all('td', class_=['teacher', 'grade'], text=True)` would find all your elements.

Comment: @jayumz: if the input HTML did not have classes, match the text content with regular expressions instead: `soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile(','))` finds all `td` elements with text with a comma.

Comment: @MartijnPieters My fault :) I didn't believe that BeautifulSoup could detect the contents in a find. A little bit of research would have helped me before I asked this question. Thank you for the quick reply and simple solution!

Comment: @jayumz: I knew this'd be a [XY problem](meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); better stick to the actual problem and not the perceived solution. :-)

Comment: Just a problem: BeautifulSoup is 10 times slower than regexes....

Comment: @eyquem Yes, they can be very cumbersome, but the Regex for this is quite challenging and could be just as difficult.

Comment: why do you esteem necessary to check the presence of ``.`` or ``,`` with a look-ahead assertion? The presence of ``grade`` or ``teacher`` should be enough to qualify the tag, shouldn't it ?

Comment: @eyquem This is true, I do that check earlier. The tag originally starts at <td nowrap>[blah]</td>. I check [blah] if it has a period or a comma, and then assign it the correct class. 

The problem comes when I try to find if the tags are blank or not. I check if it has a comma or a period to make sure it includes a grade or a teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pre-processing your HTML, trust in BeautifulSoup and use regular expression searches:

```
soup.find_all('td', text=re.compile(','))
```

finds all `<td>` elements with the *direct* text in the tag containing a comma.